# how to replace a subset of xarray.DataArray values?

Tags: python-xarray

A toy dataset from [here](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html#Toy-weather-data):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(123)

xr.set_options(display_style="html")

times = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2001-12-31", name="time")
annual_cycle = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (times.dayofyear.values / 365.25 - 0.28))

base = 10 + 15 * annual_cycle.reshape(-1, 1)
tmin_values = base + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size, 3)
tmax_values = base + 10 + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size, 3)

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "tmin": (("time", "location"), tmin_values),
        "tmax": (("time", "location"), tmax_values),
    },
    {"time": times, "location": ["IA", "IN", "IL"]},
)
```

I want to replace `tmin` values of location 0 by

```
ds.isel(location=0).tmin.values = np.arange(ds.isel(location=0).tmin.values.size)
```

or by

```
da_new = xr.DataArray(
np.arange(ds.isel(location=0).tmin.values.size),
coords={'time': times},
dims=['time']
)
ds.isel(location=0)['tmin'] = da_new
```

Both ways run without an error, but do not change the values.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to reassign a new array to the variable:

```
ar_new = ds.tmin.data
ar_new[:, 0] = np.arange(ar_new.shape[0])
ds['tmin'].data = ar_new
```

, which is not a desired way as it is not via an embedded `xarray` method and have to deal with the whole, not a subset, array of a variable.